# If a function returns a std::unique_ptr, is it reasonable to assume each returned value is to a new object?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, double-free

I'm learning about `std::unique_ptr`, trying to grok what it represents.

Given a function (out of my control) that returns a `unique_ptr`, is it implied/well understood that each invocation returns a `unique_ptr` that points to a new object (different than any prior invocation)?

By way of example, the following code produces a double-free on exit, and I hope that I correctly understand why: `unique_ptr`s delete their underlying object on destruction; therefore two `unique_ptr`s encapsulating the same memory/object would cause a double-free on destruction of the second. Therefore, would the following implementation of function `getUniquePtr()` be commonly/implicitly understood to be unreasonable?

```
// main.cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

std::unique_ptr<int> getUniquePtr() {
  static int* p = new int(42);
  return std::unique_ptr<int>(p);
}

class PtrOwner {
public:
  std::unique_ptr<int> p_;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  PtrOwner po1;
  PtrOwner po2;
  po1.p_ = getUniquePtr();
  po2.p_ = getUniquePtr();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, each `unique_ptr` *should* point to a unique object. If not then they are either using a custom deleter, which you can tell from it's signature since the deleter is part of the template parameters, to handle that or the code has a bug.

Comment: The code you posted has a bug - `p` will be `free`d twice.

Comment: A function returning a unique_ptr only transmits that this is meant to be the only **owning handle** to the object. While a factory is indeed a very common use case, in general it doesn't necessarily have to be a new object that was just created. It's not impossible to build an API that passes a unique_ptr back to the component that originally created it, followed by the the component giving ownership to some other caller under a certain set of circumstances. It's more beneficial to think about smart pointer in terms of the ownership they imply, instead of when the object was created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be assumed that, if a function returns `std::unique_ptr<T>`, then the returned smart pointer points to **an object that is not currently managed by anyone else**. This does not necessarily mean that it always refers to a different object. So long as this convention is followed, double-free bugs will be avoided. If this convention is violated, double-free bugs will occur.

For example, if you see some function like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> foo(std::unique_ptr<T> arg);
```

This function might, potentially, return `std::move(arg)` under some circumstances or it might destroy `arg` and return some other pointer. (You have to read the documentation to know what it does). This implies that you could do something like this:

```
auto t = std::make_unique<T>();
t = foo(std::move(t));
t = foo(std::move(t));
```

In this case, `foo` might just return the same pointer value twice, and this is perfectly safe. This example seems silly, but hopefully it gets my point across.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your assumptions are (mostly) correct. A `unique_ptr` owns the object exclusively, which implies that no two `unique_ptr`s should point to the same object at any given time.

As others have pointed out, this does not guarantee that multiple invocations of the same function returns different objects. This is because you can pass ownership around (by moving it), so if you pass ownership back to a function, as in Brians answer, it may well return the same object again, without braking any rules.

If you decide to manage an object by using smart pointers, try to avoid new and delete altogether. To create an object T that is owned by a `unique_ptr`, use `make_unique<T>`. This avoids the error of creating multiple `unique_ptr` to the same object. A `unique_ptr` is not copyable for exactly this reason. In other words, your getUniquePtr should be implemented like this:

```
return std::make_unique<int>(42);
```

One of the few reasons to construct a smart pointer from a raw pointer (as opposed to using make_unique) is when you have existing code or a library that works with raw pointers, which you cannot change.